# twitter hyperlink expand

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on Twitter Application, in it I get user tweets and if user share URL in it then it open in `WebView`.

But problem is that Twitter returns hyperlink like, `http://t.co/eleekj4F`.

I want to convert it in its original form as I have posted like `http://www.abcd.com/testing.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter Developer](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/9403) See other similar threads also in the same forum.

Use `expanded_url` instead of `url` from returned entities.

Answer (score -1):

I know there are some applications online that let you retrive the original url, you could maybe parse the response from them.

http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/untiny-extract-original-link-short-url/

I think you could also do it, by doing a http request to the short url and see what adress you are redirected to.

Comment: i just want to expand that hyperlink i already go threw this but not useful for me